# Android Starting Activities from Application Context

Tags: android, android-activity, applicationcontext

I am trying to start activities from a class that extends Application. I am able to do that using `FLAG_NEW_ACTIVITY_TASK` as flag intent that is creating the activity.

Let me illustrate a scenario that I am trying to implement.

There are two users USER1 and USER2. If USER1 presses a button(HOLD) a new activity is created on USER2's device. This launching of new activity on USER2's device is done by the class that extends Application. Then when USER1 presses a button(UNHOLD) I want the USER2's device to bring up the previous activity. I am able to bring up the previous activity but it is being recreated because of the `FLAG_NEW_ACTIVITY_TASK` flag, I want that activity to be resumed instead of being recreated.

I am stuck here, I did search on google but could not understand what should I do. Please Help.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RAISED_THREAD_PRIORITY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>   


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".MyApplication" >

    <service android:name=".PortSipService"></service>
    <service android:name=".Ringback"></service>

    <service android:name=".LocationService"></service>
    <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SaveContacts" android:label="@string/app_name"> </activity>
    <activity android:name=".IncomingCall" android:label="@string/app_name"> </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ContactActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CallConnected" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".OutgoingCall" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MusicPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
</application>
```

This is when on hold,

```
Intent music = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicPlayer.class);                          music.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(music);
```

This is when unhold pressed,

```
    Intent connect = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CallConnected.class);
    connect.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(connect);
```

I do not want this callconnected activity to be recreated, But it is because of the intent flag.

Comment: post your manifest and the code you use to start the activities

Comment: It sounds like you need to specify different `taskAffinity` for the different activities. Try setting `android:taskAffinity=""` on `CallConnected` activity.

Comment: @DavidWasser, I think it kind of worked, I still cannot here the communication though when pressed unhold, may be it is a server problem. I think it is working because I have a chronometer on the screen and it is still running when I switch the activities. I am learning android, I read about taskAffinity and then used it. So as you said me to assign it to CallConnected activity I did android:taskAffinity=".CallConnected". Did I do it the right way?. If so I got few problems with it as it has disturbed my activity flow a little.

Comment: You need to explain better your application in order for me to help you. How many tasks do you have? What is the expected activity flow?

Comment: Scene 1: IncomingCall-->CallConnected if answered is clicked. If USER1 clicks hold  in CallConnected another screen comes up at USER2, if USER1 clicks unhold the old CallConnected screen should come up.Scene 2: IncomingCall-->CallConnected-->HoldActivity comes up on USER2 screen, if USER1 clicks hold on the incoming screen, if USER1 clicks unhold screen comes up. Hope this will help you what I am trying to do.

Comment: No, sorry. I still don't understand your application. In any case, you can use the command `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` to view the tasks and activity stacks in your device. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try use Activity instead Context like this:

```
Intent music = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MusicPlayer.class);
music.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(music);
```